# Add href to JQuery Dialog Button

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I'm sure its very simple thing, but can't find anything.
I have a Dialog:

```
$(function() {

    $(".dialog").hide();
    $( "#dialog:ui-dialog" ).dialog( "destroy" );

    $( "#dialog-message" ).dialog({
        modal: true,
        autoOpen:false,
        width: 800,
        buttons: { "Accept": function() {alert("OK");}, "Close": function() {$(this).dialog("close");}}
    });

    $(".button").mousedown(function () {
            $("#dialog-message").show().dialog("open");
    });
});
```

And what I need is to make "Accept" button link to any url. At this time it shows alert.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Something like this?

```
"Accept": function() {window.location.href = "http://www.google.com";}
```

Comment: Yes! You made my day, thanks. It seems that I must study harder!